# Couldn't deduce template parameter 'T' for function arguments using std::conditional

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-conversion, c++14

Given this piece of code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
auto sqr(typename std::conditional<sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int), T, const T&>::type a)
{return a*a;}

int main(void)
{
    auto x = sqr<int>(10); //works
    auto y = sqr(10);      //ERROR: couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
}
```

What causes the automatic type deduction fail when calling `sqr(10)`?  Is there a way I can call `sqr()` without explicitly defining the type?

Comment: Think "pattern matching" when you look at argument deduction. How can `int` match the pattern `std::conditionl<>::type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an undeduced context here. To give an intuition as to why, note that `::type` must be the actual type of `10`, but you want it to depend on the type of `10` indirectly. So the parameter type cannot be used to deduce the result of `std::conditional`.

If you seek to "optimize" functions to pass by value, the solution is overloading with SFINAE.

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) > sizeof(int))>> // base case
auto sqr(const T& a)
{return a*a;}

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int)>> // more refined case case
auto sqr(T a)
{return a*a;}
```

---

Alternatively, and to support more conditions, you can use `std::enable_if_t` to add a SFINAE friendly non-type parameter (for example a pointer). As @Jarod42 suggested:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int), int*> = nullptr>
auto sqr(T a)
{return a*a;}
```

Comment: Better to use `std::enable_if_t<cond>* = nullptr` than `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>`: that allows to add overloads with different conditions.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Thanks. It is indeed more flexible. I do feel however that it's a bit less intuitive as an example when presenting these SFINAE-based overload culling techniques.