# Template function deduction fail on std::conditional argument

Tags: c++, templates, std, metaprogramming

*Please, before marking this as a duplicate of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831499/couldnt-deduce-template-parameter-t-for-function-arguments-using-stdconditi) question read the entirety of the post*

This piece of code fails to compile, with a template deduction error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T = float, int N>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        template<typename DATA_TYPE>
        using MyType = std::conditional_t<(N>0), DATA_TYPE, double>;
        
        MyType<T> Var;
        
        void Foo()
        {
           Bar(Var);
        }
        
        template<typename TYPE>
        void Bar(MyType<TYPE> Input)
        {
            std::cout << typeid(Input).name() << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<float, 1> c;
    c.Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I understand the point that was made in the question i linked above, which is that "the condition which allows to choose the type to be deduced depends on the type itself", however, why would the compiler fail in the specific case i provided as the condition here seems to be fully independent from the type, or is there something i'm missing?

I would be more than happy if someone could refer to a section of the c++ standard that would allow me to fully understand this behaviour.

Comment: `std::conditional_t<(N>0), DATA_TYPE, double>` is `std::conditional<true, DATA_TYPE, double>::type`, so you cannot deduce it (it is not *yet* `DATA_TYPE`).

Comment: See [template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

Comment: Oooh yes i see. So there is no way around this... so bad. i will have to do some SFINAE then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the linked question, `TYPE` is non deducible. `MyType<TYPE>` is actually `XXX<TYPE>::type`.

You have several alternatives, from your code, I would say one of

- `Bar` no longer template:

  ```
  template<typename T = float, int N>
  class MyClass
  {
      public:
          template<typename DATA_TYPE>
          using MyType = std::conditional_t<(N>0), DATA_TYPE, double>;

          MyType<T> Var;

          void Foo()
          {
             Bar(Var);
          }

          void Bar(MyType<T> Input)
          {
              std::cout << typeid(Input).name() << std::endl;
          }
  };
  ```
- `requires` (or SFINAE/specialization for pre-c++20):

  ```
  template<typename T = float, int N>
  class MyClass
  {
      public:
          template<typename DATA_TYPE>
          using MyType = std::conditional_t<(N>0), DATA_TYPE, double>;

          MyType<T> Var;

          void Foo()
          {
             Bar(Var);
          }

          template<typename TYPE>
          void Bar(TYPE Input) requires(N > 0)
          {
              std::cout << typeid(Input).name() << std::endl;
          }
          void Bar(double Input) requires(N <= 0)
          {
              std::cout << typeid(Input).name() << std::endl;
          }
  };
  ```